# Error java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Tags: java, android

My project is in Whatchap on Android Studio 3.0.1 this is my design gradle.
build.gradle (app)
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "stmik.iax.whatchap"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/sun.misc.BASE64Decoder.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.2.0'
}
```

Module Gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


                }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and this is my problem

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
> >     dex

i have been try 
1. clean project
2. rebuild project
add multiDexEnabled true

and it can't solve my problem

Comment: Solved this yet? Let us inform.

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
> dex

You should upgrade **`gms:play-service`** version.

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
```

After that, **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

**FYI**

Check **`gms:play-services`** versions. Read [**`Release Notes`**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases).